# Powershell TCP receive file slow

Tags: performance, powershell, file, sockets, tcp

This is the code for a PowerShell script which is meant to receive a file in chunks from a python server.

```
$chunkSize = {chunkSize}
$chunk= New-Object Byte[] $chunkSize
while($bytes -gt 0)
{
   if($bytes -ge $chunkSize)
   {
       $buf = $chunkSize
   }
   else
   {
       $buf = $bytes
   }
   $chunk= New-Object Byte[] $buf
   [void]$s.Read($chunk, 0, $buf)
   $file += $chunk
   $bytes -= $buf
}
set-content -value $file -encoding byte -path "$env:temp\\{filename}"
rv file;rv bytes;rv buf;rv chunkSize;rv chunk
```

As you can see, I put a `[void]` in front of the read statement which significantly shortened receive time.  However the receiving process is still very slow in 1024 byte chunks.  In my socket-based C# projects my files 
would send effortlessly with little to no lag.

With PowerShell, however, it takes forever, even after suppressing the output of the `Read` method.

Is there something I'm missing in my PowerShell script that is slowing things down?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: As an aside: don't use `\\ ` to represent a single `\ ` in PowerShell string literals - just use `\ ` - `\ ` (a single backslash) has no special meaning in PowerShell; instead, `\`` (the backtick) servers as the escape char.

Comment: Where does `$bytes` come from? It's inefficient to re-create an array in every loop iteration.

Comment: Writing to the disk is slow.  Collect everything into a variable and then write to disk.